# JWT token stored in localstorage lost after window.location.href call

Tags: javascript, .net-core, jwt, local-storage

I am using Javascript Fetch API to invoke Dot net web API.
Using Visual Studio code for HTML/Javascript & Visual Studio 2019 for Dot Net Web API.
I am trying to implement login functionality using Dot net C# Web API, that will return JWT token in the response and use the token later to invoke separate Web API/Service (e.g. EmployeeInfo ).

1. Login page :
   It displays user id and password fields and the button "Login"
2. Once user clicks on login button, the function fnlogin is invoked

```
    function fnlogin() {
        const uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
        const pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value;

        const logindata = {
            username: uname,
            password: pwd
        }
        const loginurl = 'http://localhost:13402/api/Auth/Login';
        authenticate(loginurl, logindata);        
    }
        
    async function authenticate(loginurl, logindata) {
        console.log(logindata)
        const response = await fetch(loginurl , {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            body: JSON.stringify(logindata),
            headers: { "Content-type" : "application/json, charset=UTF-8"}
        });
        const rdata = await response.json();
        console.log(rdata);
        if (!rdata.success) {
            document.getElementById("loginMessage").innerHTML = rdata.message;
            return;
        }

        const inMemoryToken = rdata.data
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(rdata));
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:5500/Employeeinfo1.html";

    }
```

3. The Web API returns JWT token properly.

The code in controller is as follows :

```
        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<string>>> Login(UserLoginDto request)
        {
            var response = await _authRepo.Login(
                request.Username, request.Password
            );

            if (!response.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(response);
            }

            return Ok(response);
        }

``
The code in AuthRepository class is as follows :
```

```
public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public AuthRepository(AppDbContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _context = context;

    }

    public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var response = new ServiceResponse<string>();
        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username.ToLower().Equals(username.ToLower()));
        if (user == null)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "User not found.";
        }
        else if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "Wrong password.";
        }
        else
        {
            response.Data = CreateToken(user);
        }

        return response;
    }

    public async Task<ServiceResponse<User>> Register(User user, string password)
    {
        ServiceResponse<User> response = new ServiceResponse<User>();
        if (await UserExists(user.Username))
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "User already exists.";
            return response;
        }

        CreatePasswordHash(password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

        _context.Users.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        response.Data = user;
        return response;
    }

    public async Task<bool> UserExists(string username)
    {
        if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.Username.ToLower().Equals(username.ToLower())))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
            passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }

    private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
        {
            var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computedHash[i] != passwordHash[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private string CreateToken(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokendDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokendDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

```
4. Once the JWT token is returned , it is stored in LocalStorage. I verified in Chrome Dev Tools

But after the next screen is displayed, when I check in Chrome dev tools, the object/token is no longer present in the Local Storage.
Is this because of window.location.href will remove all local data in localStorage in the browser ?

I want to be able to use the token to pass to remaining html screens and web api
```

Comment: What is the URL of the page where the code that stores the item in the local storage is run? You might be storing it in one origin and trying to read if from another (`http://localhost:5500`).

Comment: The url of the login page is http://127.0.0.1:5500/login.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing an item in the local storage of `http://127.0.0.1:5500` and trying to read it from `http://localhost:5500`.

From [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in MDN Web Docs:

> The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin;

And about [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin):

> Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), host (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, host, and port all match.

As you see, for the browser the origins are different because the host does not match: `127.0.0.1` is not the same string as `localhost`.

Use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` everywhere, but do not use both.

Comment: My understanding was localhost and 127.0.0.1 are same.. I guess there is some difference,  I changed and it worked.. Thank you

Comment: @SudhirJangam, `localhost` is a hostname that generally refers to `127.0.0.1`, in that sense you can consider it the same. A browser does a strict string comparison to determine the origin, and as `"localhost"` is not equal to `"127.0.0.1"` it decides that the origin is different.